# php - Encode string two-way to move to another server

Tags: php, python, encryption, sed

I have a string that is user input that is sent from one server to another using python. This string is then put through 'sed' to input it into a file.

This input cannot contain all sorts of characters such as:

```
\'/"
```

Or it will break the code... I know right, good design!!.... /s

Is there a way for me to encrypt it to only an alphanumeric string like:

```
43oi5u3948jf98ey87yd8f79gy8d7fhgo8eruhg
```

Which I can then decrypt on the other end back to the original string containing all the annoying characters that break code?

I have tried to look online but I can't find this specific issue.

Cheers

Comment: Does it need to be encrypted, or are you just asking for something that can be encoded and decoded?

Comment: Are you just trying to stop interception?

Comment: Something that can be encoded and decoded. And yes I am trying to stop interception @dragon. Thanks

Comment: SSL/HTTPS:// would be my choice

Comment: To avoid [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) your question is actually: *How can I securely transfer some data from one server to another?* You were about to reinvent PGP...

Comment: you want to encrypt or just transform data to alphanumeric?

Comment: If you just want to make sure that an attacker cannot change or add characters then TLS is sufficient. Please indicate if that's sufficient. If it's not, explain why.

Comment: People are picky even though I updated my title to 'encoding'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). It converts any data into an ASCII string.

Online encoder/decoder: [base64decode.org](https://www.base64decode.org/)

Examples:

```
This is a string --> VGhpcyBpcyBhIHN0cmluZw==
StackOverflow    --> U3RhY2tPdmVyZmxvdw==
foobar           --> Zm9vYmFy
```

Note that the encoded data will be about 4/3 the size of the original data.

([Base85/Acii85](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85) is the same thing but a little bit more compact)